# Convert JSON String to JSON Object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, string, parsing

I have this String stored in my database:

```
str = "{ "context_name": { "lower_bound": "value", "upper_bound": "value", "values": [ "value1", "valueN" ] } }"
```

This string is already in the JSON format but I want to convert it into a JObject or JSON Object.

```
JObject json = new JObject();
```

I tried the `json = (JObject)str;` cast but it didn't work so how can I do it?

Comment: Use `JObject.Parse("...")`

Answer (score 418, accepted):

`JObject` defines method `Parse` for this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

You might want to refer to Json.NET [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

Comment: This will convert to {string}, will add extra curly brackets to your string.

Comment: way to avoid extra curly brackets
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331606/4067905

Answer (score 127):

if you don't want or need a typed object try:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// ...   
dynamic json  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
```

or try for a typed object try:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// single    
Foo foo  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(str);

// or as a list
List<Foo> foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(str);
```

Comment: This will also work with list of T if the incoming json string contains a collection: 

    List<Foo> json  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Foo>>(str)

Answer (score 26):

This works

```
    string str = "{ 'context_name': { 'lower_bound': 'value', 'pper_bound': 'value', 'values': [ 'value1', 'valueN' ] } }";
    JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    object a = j.Deserialize(str, typeof(object));
```

Comment: namespace for 'JavaScriptSerializer': System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Comment: Definitely worked for me. Using JObject after replaced double quotes for single quote, did the trick. Thanks!!!

Comment: System.Web.Script.Serialization is only available in .Net full framework.

Answer (score 7):

there's an interesting way to achive another goal which is to have a strongly type class base on json with a very powerfull tools that i used few days ago for first time to translate tradedoubler json result into classes

Is a simple tool: copy your json source paste and in few second [you will have a strongly typed class json oriented](http://json2csharp.com/) .
In this manner you will use these classes which is more powerful and simply to use.

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=C%23 and https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Answer (score 7):

You can try like following:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using `JsonConvert`

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(responseString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your JSon string has "" double quote instead of a single quote ' and has \n as a indicator of a next line then you need to remove it because that's not a proper JSon string, example as shown below:

```
            SomeClass dna = new SomeClass ();
            string response = wc.DownloadString(url);
            string strRemSlash = response.Replace("\"", "\'");
            string strRemNline = strRemSlash.Replace("\n", " ");
            // Time to desrialize it to convert it into an object class.
            dna = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(@strRemNline);
```

Answer (score 1):

In a situation where you are retrieving a list of objects of a certain entity from your api, your response string may look like this:

```
[{"id":1,"nome":"eeee","username":null,"email":null},{"id":2,"nome":"eeee","username":null,"email":null},{"id":3,"nome":"Ricardo","username":null,"email":null}]
```

In this situation you may want an array of Jason objects and cycle through them to populate your c# variable. I've done like so:

```
var httpResponse = await Http.GetAsync($"api/{entidadeSelecionada}");
    List<List<string[]>> Valores = new();
    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //totalPagesQuantity = int.Parse(httpResponse.Headers.GetValues("pagesQuantity").FirstOrDefault());
        //Aqui tenho que colocar um try para o caso de ser retornado um objecto vazio
        var responseString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        JArray array = JArray.Parse(responseString);

        foreach (JObject objx in array.Children<JObject>())
        {
            List<string[]> ls = new();
            foreach (JProperty singleProp in objx.Properties())
            {
                if (!singleProp.Name.Contains("_xyz"))
                {
                    string[] val = new string[2];
                    val[0] = singleProp.Name;
                    val[1] = singleProp.Value.ToString();
                    ls.Add(val);
                }
            }
            Valores.Add(ls);
        }
    }
    return Valores;
```

I achieved this solution by the @Andrei answer.

Answer (score 0):

This does't work in case of the JObject this works for the simple json format data. I have tried my data of the below json format data to deserialize in the type but didn't get the response.

For this Json

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "id": "Shell",
    "Installations": [
      {
        "id": "Shell.Bangalore",
        "Stations": [
          {
            "id": "Shell.Bangalore.BTM",
            "Pumps": [
              {
                "id": "Shell.Bangalore.BTM.pump1"
              },
              {
                "id": "Shell.Bangalore.BTM.pump2"
              },
              {
                "id": "Shell.Bangalore.BTM.pump3"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "Shell.Bangalore.Madiwala",
            "Pumps": [
              {
                "id": "Shell.Bangalore.Madiwala.pump4"
              },
              {
                "id": "Shell.Bangalore.Madiwala.pump5"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<ListView11> _Resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ListView11>>(result);
            //List<ListView11> _objList = new List<ListView11>((IEnumerable<ListView11>)_Resp);

            IList usll = _Resp.Select(a => a.lttsdata).ToList();
            // List<ListViewClass> _objList = new List<ListViewClass>((IEnumerable<ListViewClass>)_Resp);
            //IList usll = _objList.OrderBy(a=> a.ReqID).ToList();
            Lv.ItemsSource = usll;
```