# How to convert array(string[]) to JsonValue?

Tags: c#, json

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Json;

namespace StackOverflowQuestion
{
    class StackOverflowQuestion
    {
        public StackOverflowQuestion()
        {
            JsonObject  jsonObj = new JsonObject();
            string[] arr = { "first_value", "second_value", "third_value"          };
            obj.Add("array", arr ); // Compiler cannot convert string[] to System.Json.JsonValue

        }
    }
}
```

I want to receive in result Json object like

```
{"array":["first_value","second_value","third_value"]"}
```

Comment: Don't use JavaScriptSerializer. It's obsolete. Microsoft itself uses Json.NET

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper class that you serialize that has an "Array" property. This will allow the JSON serialized object to have the "Array" field name you are looking for.

```
var array = { "first_value", "second_value", "third_value" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JsonArray
{
    Array = array,
    Some_Field = true
});

public class JsonArray
{
    public string[] Array { get; set; }

    public bool Some_Field { get; set; }
}
```

Note, this uses Json.NET, which you can download/find more info about here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Okay. But how to generate such json:
    {"some_field":true,"array":["first_value","second_value","third_value"]"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaScriptSerializer` instead of declaring a `JsonObject`

```
string[] arr = { "first_value", "second_value", "third_value"          };
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870647/5248655).

Answer (score 0):

Download/install NuGet package "*Newtonsoft.Json*" and then try this:

```
string[] arr = { "first_value", "second_value", "third_value"};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
```

So there is no Wrapper and so the `json`-string is looking like this:

```
[
   "first_value",
   "second_value",
   "third_value"
]
```

If you would use a warpper (Person.class) with data in it, it would look like this:

```
// Structure....
Person
   private String name;
   private String lastName;
   private String[] arr;   // for your example...

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
{
    "Person": {
        "name": "<VALUE>",
        "lastName": <VALUE>,
        "arr":[
             "first_value",
             "second_value",
             "third_value"
        ]
    }
}
```