# Have a Json data in a variable and want to display that data in Tabular form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, tabular

I want to convert this into tabular format using ASP.NET

```
responsebody= [{
        "name": "apple.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.com",
        "status": "available",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "apple.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    }]
```

Comment: can you add more details in the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981282/convert-json-to-datatable)

Comment: what kind of additional information do you need?@Manish

Comment: @ThinleyNamgay you can improve the quality of your question by adding a clear title/summary, providing more background on what you are trying to do, explain what  approaches you have tried, and why they didn't work. More advice: [ask].

Comment: I want to display the above Json string on a webpage in table format.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer depends on whether you are using ASP.NET MVC or WebForms, build-in types or 3rd party libraries.

Here is an example for MVC.

**1. Your Controller Action would look similar to:**

```
public ActionResult DisplayJsonData()
        {
            var json = @"{
                'items' : [{
                        'name': 'apple.com',
                        'status': 'regthroughothers',
                        'classkey': 'domcno'
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'asdfgqwx.com',
                        'status': 'available',
                        'classkey': 'domcno'
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'microsoft.org',
                        'status': 'unknown',
                        'classkey': ''
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'apple.org',
                        'status': 'unknown',
                        'classkey': ''
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'microsoft.com',
                        'status': 'regthroughothers',
                        'classkey': 'domcno'
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'asdfgqwx.org',
                        'status': 'unknown',
                        'classkey': 'domcno'
                    }
                ]
            }"; 

            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DisplayJsonModel>(json);
            return View(model);
        }
```

**And DisplayJsonData.cshtml view:**

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.DisplayJsonModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayJsonData";
}

<h2>DisplayJsonData</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Class Key</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.name</td>
                <td>@item.status</td>
                <td>@item.classkey</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

3. As suggested above you would need to parse JSON as well.

   public class DisplayJsonModel
       {
           public JsonItem[] Items { get; set; }
       }

   ```
   public class JsonItem
   {
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string status { get; set; }
       public string classkey { get; set; }
   }
   ```

---

**And here is pure JS:**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Class Key</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="jsTableBody"></tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var responsebody = [
        {
            "name": "apple.com",
            "status": "regthroughothers",
            "classkey": "domcno"
        },
        {
            "name": "asdfgqwx.com",
            "status": "available",
            "classkey": "domcno"
        },
        {
            "name": "microsoft.org",
            "status": "unknown",
            "classkey": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "apple.org",
            "status": "unknown",
            "classkey": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "microsoft.com",
            "status": "regthroughothers",
            "classkey": "domcno"
        },
        {
            "name": "asdfgqwx.org",
            "status": "unknown",
            "classkey": "domcno"
        }
    ];

    var tableRows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < responsebody.length; i++) {
        tableRows.push("<tr>" +
            "<td>" + responsebody[i].name + "</td>" + 
            "<td>" + responsebody[i].status + "</td>" + 
            "<td>" + responsebody[i].classkey + "</td>" + 
            "</tr>");
    }
    var tableBody = document.getElementById("jsTableBody");
    tableBody.innerHTML = tableRows.join('');
</script>
```

---

**And for Web Forms**
You might want to look into using something like asp:DataGrid in aspx page:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-bordered">
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="classkey" HeaderText="Class Key" />
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

And in code-behind:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DisplayJsonModel>(json);
grid.DataSource = model.Items;
grid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using webforms to display the table in a webpage.

Comment: Update the answer with a possible web forms variant.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `Newtonsoft.JsonConvert` NuGet package to convert your JSON to a C#-compatible type. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer and then click "Manage NuGet Packages", then search for and install it.

You'll also need to create a new class to store the data in the correct format. Right-click on your project, hover on "Add", click on "Class". Assuming all your data is string format:

```
public class Data
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string classkey { get; set; }
    }
```

Back to wherever your JSON variable is, add `using Newtonsoft.Json;`, then use code like below:

`List<Data> deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(your variable name here);`

This will get your data in a List of type Data. From there you can insert it into a SQLite database or do whatever, but you'll need to make your question more specific on what you mean by "tabular".

Answer (score 0):

In **Visual Studio**

Step 1: Copy your `JSON` to `clipboard` by `right-click` or (`CtrC` + `C`):

```
[{
        "name": "apple.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.com",
        "status": "available",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "apple.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "microsoft.com",
        "status": "regthroughothers",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    },
    {
        "name": "asdfgqwx.org",
        "status": "unknown",
        "classkey": "domcno"
    }]
```

Step 2: Put your pointer into the position you want to write that.

Select `Edit` >> `Paste Special` >> `Paste JSON as Classes`

> Result:

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string classkey { get; set; }
    }
```

Step3: You can change something with the result you want. Then, Using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(yourString)` to do the work.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have already created this class.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870624/convert-json-string-to-json-object-c-sharp), @ThinleyNamgay