# Creating a Class in C# from JSON File

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm very new to C#, although I've done some dabbling in VB years ago.

I created a basic Windows form with a multi-line textbox and am writing the contents of a text file to the textbox:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"X:\Log Files\01.log").ToList();

        lines.ForEach(l => {

            textBox1.AppendText(l);
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                    });

    }
```

I did this so I could see that I was actually reading the contents of the file.  I know... you're all very impressed by this amazing bit of skill.

So, here are some lines from the text file:

```
{ "timestamp":"2020-01-03T00:20:22Z", "event":"Rank", "Rank1":3, "Rank2":8 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-01-03T00:20:22Z", "event":"Progress", "Task1":56, "Task2":100 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-01-03T00:20:22Z", "event":"Reputation", "Nation":75.000000, "State":75.000000 }
{ "timestamp":"2020-01-03T00:20:27Z", "event":"Music", "MusicTrack":"NoTrack" }
```

I want to create objects based on the event types.  Something like:

```
   public Progress(int time, int t1, int t2)
   {
        this.timestamp = time;  //'time' is the timestamp value from the line
        this.task1 = t1;        //'t1' is the Task1 value from the line
        this.task2 = t2;        //'t2' is the Task2 value from the line
   }
```

When reading the file, it would take the `event` field and use that to determine the class to instantiate. The `timestamp` for that line would be retained and the fields for each event would then be populated as properties for the class.

I've installed `Newtonsoft.Json` into Visual Studio and I assume this has the ability natively to do this.

But, I can't see in the documentation how to do this.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON, it looks like newline-delimited JSON (basically a sequence of JSON objects concatenated together).  To read such a file see [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063).

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870624/convert-json-string-to-json-object-c-sharp)

Comment: For future, `textbox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("c:\\my.txt");` is a more succinct way of reading a file into a textbox. Using http://quicktype.io is a good way to quickly generate c# classes that serialise and deserialise json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works on my machine. You need to add event sub classes (the ones that are derived from `BaseEvent`, i.e. `RankEvent`) for all your additional events in your .log file and also add properties to the `JsonEvent` class for these and add values to the `EventType` and update the `switch statement`.

**How I did this:**

1. I copied each line from your .log file
2. I.e. `{ "timestamp":"2020-01-03T00:20:22Z", "event":"Rank", "Rank1":3, "Rank2":8 }`
3. I went [here](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) and pasted the line into the left window to get a C# class, then I created a combined `JsonEvent` class from all of the lines.
4. I made the [primitive types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table) [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) because after each parse loop, some of the properties will be null
5. I made a base class `BaseEvent` with common properties (in this case just `Timestamp`)
6. I made sub classes of the `BaseEvent` for each event, i.e.  `RankEvent`
7. I made an event enum `EventType` to parse the `"event"` property.
8. I looped through all lines, for each line I Deserialize the line into a JsonEvent C# class (`jsonEvent`) and looked at the `EventType` to know which sub class I should create.
9. For each loop, I parsed/deserialized a sub class (`newEvent`) into a list of `List<BaseEvent> eventList`
10. When the loop is done, the `eventList` variable is populated and ready to be used in the rest of the program.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var file = @"X:\Log Files\01.log";
            var eventList = ParseEvents(file);
            //TODO Do something
        }

        private static List<BaseEvent> ParseEvents(string file)
        {
            //TODO Encapsulate in a try & catch and add a logger for error handling
            var eventList = new List<BaseEvent>();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var jsonEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonEvent>(line);
                BaseEvent newEvent;
                switch (jsonEvent.EventType)
                {
                    case EventType.Rank:
                        newEvent = new RankEvent(jsonEvent);
                        eventList.Add(newEvent);
                        break;
                    case EventType.Progress:
                        newEvent = new ProgressEvent(jsonEvent);
                        eventList.Add(newEvent);
                        break;
                    case EventType.Reputation:
                        newEvent = new ReputationEvent(jsonEvent);
                        eventList.Add(newEvent);
                        break;
                    case EventType.Music:
                        newEvent = new MusicEvent(jsonEvent);
                        eventList.Add(newEvent);
                        break;

                    //TODO Add more cases for each EventType

                    default:
                        throw new Exception(String.Format("Unknown EventType: {0}", jsonEvent.EventType));
                }
            }

            return eventList;
        }
    }

    //TODO Move classes/enums to a separate folder

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum EventType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "Rank")]
        Rank,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Progress")]
        Progress,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Reputation")]
        Reputation,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Music")]
        Music,

        //TODO Add more enum values for each "event"
    }

    public abstract class BaseEvent
    {
        public BaseEvent(DateTime timestamp)
        {
            Timestamp = timestamp;
        }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class RankEvent : BaseEvent
    {
        public RankEvent(JsonEvent jsonEvent) : base(jsonEvent.Timestamp)
        {
            Rank1 = jsonEvent.Rank1.Value;
            Rank2 = jsonEvent.Rank2.Value;
        }
        public int Rank1 { get; set; }
        public int Rank2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProgressEvent : BaseEvent
    {
        public ProgressEvent(JsonEvent jsonEvent) : base(jsonEvent.Timestamp)
        {
            Task1 = jsonEvent.Task1.Value;
            Task2 = jsonEvent.Task2.Value;
        }
        public int Task1 { get; set; }
        public int Task2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReputationEvent : BaseEvent
    {
        public ReputationEvent(JsonEvent jsonEvent) : base(jsonEvent.Timestamp)
        {
            Nation = jsonEvent.Nation.Value;
            State = jsonEvent.State.Value;
        }
        public double Nation { get; set; }
        public double State { get; set; }
    }

    public class MusicEvent : BaseEvent
    {
        public MusicEvent(JsonEvent jsonEvent) : base(jsonEvent.Timestamp)
        {
            MusicTrack = jsonEvent.MusicTrack;
        }
        public string MusicTrack { get; set; }
    }

    //TODO Add more derived sub classes of the BaseEvent

    [JsonObject]
    public class JsonEvent
    {
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("event")]
        public EventType EventType { get; set; }
        public int? Rank1 { get; set; }
        public int? Rank2 { get; set; }
        public int? Task1 { get; set; }
        public int? Task2 { get; set; }
        public double? Nation { get; set; }
        public double? State { get; set; }
        public string MusicTrack { get; set; }

        //TODO Add more properties
    }
}
```

`eventList` Quickwatch:
[image]

**Additional reading:**

**Parse Json to C#**

[How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/deserialize-different-json-object-same-class/

**Debugging in Visual Studio**

(always set a breakpoint on a line with F9, then hit F5 and step through your code with F10/F11, it gives much insight into how the code behaves)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

**Tools for creating C# classes from Json:**

https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DangKhuong.JSONtoC

---

**UPDATE:
I made an additional script that creates the above C# sub classes for you:**

Just run this script and all classes (including `Program.cs`) will be created.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CreateFiles
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var file = @"X:\Log Files\01.log";
            var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            //Change outPutPath to your choosing
            var outPutPath = Path.Combine(desktop, "Temp");
            //Change namespaceName to your choosing
            var namespaceName = "StackOverFlow";
            var uniqueList = GetUniqueEventTypeList(file);
            CreateBaseClass(outPutPath, namespaceName);
            CreateEventClasses(uniqueList, outPutPath, namespaceName);
            CreateEnumClass(uniqueList, outPutPath, namespaceName);
            CreateJsonEventClass(uniqueList, outPutPath, namespaceName);
            CreateProgramClass(uniqueList, outPutPath, namespaceName);
            Console.WriteLine($"\nParsing done! Classes parsed to {outPutPath}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static List<string> GetUniqueEventTypeList(string file)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
            var uniqueEventTypes = new List<string>();
            var uniqueList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(line);
                var eventType = json["event"].Value<string>();
                if (!uniqueEventTypes.Exists(e => e.Equals(eventType)))
                {
                    uniqueEventTypes.Add(eventType);
                    uniqueList.Add(line);
                }
            }
            return uniqueList;
        }

        private static void CreateEventClasses(List<string> lines, string path, string namespaceName)
        {
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var jObj = JObject.Parse(line);
                CreateEventClass(jObj, path, namespaceName);
            }
        }

        public class ParseClass
        {
            public ParseClass(KeyValuePair<string, JToken> obj)
            {
                Name = obj.Key;
                SetType(obj.Value);
            }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public bool IsPrimitive { get; set; }

            private void SetType(JToken token)
            {
                switch (token.Type)
                {
                    case JTokenType.Integer:
                        Type = "int";
                        IsPrimitive = true;
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Float:
                        Type = "double";
                        IsPrimitive = true;
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.String:
                        Type = "string";
                        IsPrimitive = false;
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Boolean:
                        Type = "bool";
                        IsPrimitive = true;
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Date:
                        Type = "DateTime";
                        IsPrimitive = true;
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Guid:
                        Type = "Guid";
                        IsPrimitive = true;
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Uri:
                        Type = "Uri";
                        IsPrimitive = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception($"Unknown type {token.Type}");
                }
            }
        }

        private static void CreateProgramClass(List<string> lines, string path, string namespaceName)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var className = "Program";
            var fileName = $"{className}.cs";
            var file = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            try
            {
                // Create a new file     
                using (FileStream fsStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fsStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    //The Program class needed these bytes in the beginning to work
                    sw.WriteLine("using Newtonsoft.Json;");
                    sw.WriteLine("using System;");
                    sw.WriteLine("using System.Collections.Generic;");
                    sw.WriteLine("using System.IO;");
                    sw.WriteLine("using System.Linq;");
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                    sw.WriteLine($"namespace {namespaceName}");
                    sw.WriteLine("{");
                    sw.WriteLine($"    public class {className}");
                    sw.WriteLine("    {");
                    sw.WriteLine($"        static void Main(string[] args)");
                    sw.WriteLine("        {");
                    sw.WriteLine("            var file = @\"X:\\Log Files\\01.log\";");
                    sw.WriteLine("            var eventList = ParseEvents(file);");
                    sw.WriteLine("            //TODO Do something");
                    sw.WriteLine("        }");
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                    sw.WriteLine("        private static List<BaseEvent> ParseEvents(string file)");
                    sw.WriteLine("        {");
                    sw.WriteLine("            //TODO Encapsulate in a try & catch and add a logger for error handling");
                    sw.WriteLine("            var eventList = new List<BaseEvent>();");
                    sw.WriteLine("            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();");
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                    sw.WriteLine("            foreach (var line in lines)");
                    sw.WriteLine("            {");
                    sw.WriteLine("                var jsonEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonEvent>(line);");
                    sw.WriteLine("                BaseEvent newEvent;");
                    sw.WriteLine("                switch (jsonEvent.EventType)");
                    sw.WriteLine("                {");
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        var jObj = JObject.Parse(line);
                        var eventType = jObj["event"].Value<string>();
                        sw.WriteLine($"                    case EventType.{eventType}:");
                        sw.WriteLine($"                        newEvent = new {eventType}Event(jsonEvent);");
                        sw.WriteLine($"                        eventList.Add(newEvent);");
                        sw.WriteLine($"                        break;");
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine("                    default:");
                    sw.WriteLine("                        throw new Exception(String.Format(\"Unknown EventType: {0} \", jsonEvent.EventType));");
                    sw.WriteLine("                }");
                    sw.WriteLine("            }");
                    sw.WriteLine("            return eventList;");
                    sw.WriteLine("        }");
                    sw.WriteLine("    }");
                    sw.WriteLine("}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Created {fileName}.");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void CreateEnumClass(List<string> lines, string path, string namespaceName)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path));
            var className = "EventType";
            var fileName = $"{className}.cs";
            var file = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

            try
            {
                // Check if file already exists. If yes, throw exception.     
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"{file} already exists!");
                }

                // Create a new file     
                using (FileStream fsStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fsStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("using Newtonsoft.Json;");
                    sw.WriteLine("using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;");
                    sw.WriteLine("using System.Runtime.Serialization;");
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                    sw.WriteLine($"namespace {namespaceName}");
                    sw.WriteLine("{");
                    sw.WriteLine($"    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]");
                    sw.WriteLine($"    public enum {className}");
                    sw.WriteLine("    {");
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        var jObj = JObject.Parse(line);
                        var eventType = jObj["event"].Value<string>();
                        sw.WriteLine($"        [EnumMember(Value = \"{eventType}\")]");
                        sw.WriteLine($"        {eventType},");
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine("    }");
                    sw.WriteLine("}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Created {fileName}.");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void CreateJsonEventClass(List<string> lines, string path, string namespaceName)
        {

            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var className = "JsonEvent";
            var fileName = $"{className}.cs";
            var file = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

            var propertyList = new List<ParseClass>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var jObject = JObject.Parse(line);
                foreach (var obj in jObject)
                {
                    if (!(obj.Key.Equals("event") || obj.Key.Equals("timestamp")))
                    {
                        propertyList.Add(new ParseClass(obj));
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                // Check if file already exists. If yes, throw exception.     
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"{file} already exists!");
                }
                // Create a new file     
                using (FileStream fsStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fsStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("using Newtonsoft.Json;");
                    sw.WriteLine("using System;");
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                    sw.WriteLine($"namespace {namespaceName}");
                    sw.WriteLine("{");
                    sw.WriteLine($"    [JsonObject]");
                    sw.WriteLine($"    public class {className}");
                    sw.WriteLine("{");
                    sw.WriteLine("        [JsonProperty(\"timestamp\")]");
                    sw.WriteLine("        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }");
                    sw.WriteLine("        [JsonProperty(\"event\")]");
                    sw.WriteLine("        public EventType EventType { get; set; }");
                    foreach (var property in propertyList)
                    {
                        var type = property.IsPrimitive ? property.Type + "?" : property.Type;
                        sw.WriteLine("        public " + type + " " + property.Name + " { get; set; }");
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine("    }");
                    sw.WriteLine("}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Created {fileName}.");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void CreateBaseClass(string path, string namespaceName)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var className = $"BaseEvent";
            var fileName = $"{className}.cs";
            var file = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

            try
            {
                // Check if file already exists. If yes, throw exception.     
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"{file} already exists!");
                }

                // Create a new file     
                using (StreamWriter sw = fi.CreateText())
                {
                    sw.WriteLine($"using System;");
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                    sw.WriteLine($"namespace {namespaceName}");
                    sw.WriteLine("{");
                    sw.WriteLine($"    public abstract class BaseEvent");
                    sw.WriteLine("    {");
                    sw.WriteLine($"        public BaseEvent(DateTime timestamp)");
                    sw.WriteLine("        {");
                    sw.WriteLine($"            Timestamp = timestamp;");
                    sw.WriteLine("        }");
                    sw.WriteLine("        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }");
                    sw.WriteLine("    }");
                    sw.WriteLine("}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Created {fileName}.");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void CreateEventClass(JObject jObject, string path, string namespaceName)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var eventName = $"{jObject["event"].Value<string>()}";
            var className = $"{eventName}Event";
            var fileName = $"{className}.cs";
            var file = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

            var propertyList = new List<ParseClass>();
            foreach (var obj in jObject)
            {
                if (!(obj.Key.Equals("event") || obj.Key.Equals("timestamp")))
                {
                    propertyList.Add(new ParseClass(obj));
                }
            }

            try
            {
                // Check if file already exists. If yes, throw exception.     
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"{file} already exists!");
                }

                // Create a new file     
                using (FileStream fsStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fsStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine($"namespace {namespaceName}");
                    sw.WriteLine("{");
                    sw.WriteLine($"    public class {className} : BaseEvent");
                    sw.WriteLine("    {");
                    sw.WriteLine($"        public {className}(JsonEvent jsonEvent) : base(jsonEvent.Timestamp)");
                    sw.WriteLine("        {");
                    foreach (var property in propertyList)
                    {
                        var name = property.IsPrimitive ? $"{property.Name}.Value" : $"{property.Name}";
                        sw.WriteLine($"            {property.Name} = jsonEvent.{name};");
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine("        }");
                    foreach (var property in propertyList)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("        public " + property.Type + " " + property.Name + " { get; set; }");
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine("    }");
                    sw.WriteLine("}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Created {fileName}.");
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Joel, thank so much for all the detail.  I've got some work to do today and plan on playing around with this tomorrow or this evening.    I truly appreciate the links for additional reading, too.  I need to educate my self on this stuff.

Comment: @jchornsey No problems! Just for fun, I made an additional script that creates the above C# classes for you. See the update!

Comment: I'm not sure you're allowed to say "just for fun" in that context.  LOL.

Comment: This stuff is so over my head (I can't even figure out how to change the text on a label in my main window to list the event name LOL), but I'm learning thanks to what you've posted.  Thank you!  This has definitely put me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possibilities here. Both are not very beautiful:

1. Create a single class with all properties
2. Check each line for the occurrence of a key word (like Rank, Task,
   Nation). Based on that you could select the class to be created.

A third option comes to mind. You could write your own converter for Json.net:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to
- https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: Christian, I appreciate your response.  I'll look at those links.  I don't have a lot of confidence in my ability to write much of anything, let alone a converter for Json.net.  LOL