# How to get sentence from a string C# string manipulation

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get additional info from the string

```
string input= "status":404,"userMessage":"ERROR CODE: EBE04005 | SEVERITY: E | SOURCE IDENTIFIER: EBE04 | DESCRIPTION: The User Profile Retrieval Service was unable to process due to an unavailable Data Source: | Additional Info: Prodcucer Detail Not Found In Producer DB For Producer Code: 123456"
```

the desired output is:

> Producer Detail Not Found In Producer DB For Producer Code: 123456

for this i am trying to

```
string input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("Info:"))
```

but not getting the desired result. below is the output

> Info: Producer Detail Not Found In Producer DB For Producer Code: 123456

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: This string is JSON. Use [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and deserialize it to object and read property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870624/convert-json-string-to-json-object-c-sharp

Comment: @BWA it is not a valid JSON ... even if ... he wants a part from `userMessage` property

Comment: @BWAthat's not JSON. Even if it was, the information would be *inside* a string property. JSON parsing wouldn't help

Comment: @Selvin oops, wrong tag

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Selvin OP miss "{" , and when he get proprer userMessage string he can ask how to get that info

Comment: That's not even a valid string...

Comment: @Sam you can use a regex that catches everything after `Additional Info:`, eg `Additional Info:\s*(?<content>.*)` will catch everything after `Additional Info:` in the `content` group

Comment: @BWA as I said, even if this was a JSON string, you'd still have to parse the string property to get the required info. JSON.NET isn't the solution here, not even part of it

Comment: @Sam what is the *actual* string? It matters - Does `Additional Info:` appear last? Can there be a separator after it? Is there a `}` or not? Each case requires different regular expressions

Comment: if it is always at the end you could split: `input.Split(new string[] {"Additional Info:"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Last()` and take the last part, which would be your message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted will use the start of the `Info` marker, so you need to add a bit.

```
string input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("Info:") + "Info:".Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle if your word isnt in the string.

```
string toBeSearched = "Info:";
int io= myString.IndexOf(toBeSearched);

if (io!= -1) 
{
    string code = myString.Substring(io+ toBeSearched.Length);
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/qDZVw9/1) for the purpose. For example,

```
var match = Regex.Match(input,@"Additional Info:\s*(?<AdditionalInfo>[^\""]*)");
if(match.Success)
{
  var additionalInfo = match.Groups["AdditionalInfo"].Value;
}
```

In the above code, the Regex.Match method searches input string for the specified Regex Expression. On finding a match, named groups are used to extract the AdditionalInfo

Output

```
Prodcucer Detail Not Found In Producer DB For Producer Code: 123456
```

Answer (score 1):

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m0qUbq
Since the location of the string of interest is in the rear most of the input string, recommended using `LastIndexOf`

```
string input= "... Data Source: | Additional Info: Prodcucer Detail Not Found In Producer DB For Producer Code: 123456";
input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("Info: ") + "Info: ".Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string is JSON, in your example is missing "{" at the beginning, but i think you have valid JSON in app.

This code gets all info from your message:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Json.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input= "{\"status\":404,\"userMessage\":\"ERROR CODE: EBE04005 | SEVERITY: E | SOURCE IDENTIFIER: EBE04 | DESCRIPTION: The User Profile Retrieval Service was unable to process due to an unavailable Data Source: | Additional Info: Prodcucer Detail Not Found In Producer DB For Producer Code: 123456\"}";

            Data data = JsonNet.Deserialize<Data>(input);

            string[] messages = data.userMessage.Split('|');

            Dictionary<string, string> messageDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (string message in messages)
            {
                string[] tmp = message.Split(':');
                messageDict.Add(tmp[0].Trim(), tmp[1].Trim());
            }

            foreach (string key in messageDict.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {key} Value: {messageDict[key]}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int status { get; set; }

        public string userMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And output:

```
Key: ERROR CODE Value: EBE04005
Key: SEVERITY Value: E
Key: SOURCE IDENTIFIER Value: EBE04
Key: DESCRIPTION Value: The User Profile Retrieval Service was unable to process due to an unavailable Data Source
Key: Additional Info Value: Prodcucer Detail Not Found In Producer DB For Producer Code
```