# azure ad list users into combobox graph api C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm currently working on an application where i need to get all the users from the company's azure ad

I manage to make a select and get all users into the ResultText textblock.

i now use the DisplayBasicTokenInfo() to fill a textbox but it only returns 1 username and that's my own. Now what i want to do is make a list of all the users and load these into a combobox via DisplayBasicTokenInfo.

I don't know if this is the best solution but it is what i found. The end goal for this is that i want every Displayname to be a comboboxItem

This is the code i have so far.

```
 public partial class TestGraphApi : Window
{
    //Set the API Endpoint to Graph 'users' endpoint
    string _graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName";

    //Set the scope for API call to user.read.all
    string[] _scopes = new string[] { "user.read.all" };

    public TestGraphApi()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Call AcquireTokenAsync - to acquire a token requiring user to sign-in
    /// </summary>
    private async void CallGraphButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        var app = App.PublicClientApp;
        ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
        TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;

        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
        var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

        try
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, firstAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
            // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                    .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
            return;
        }

        if (authResult != null)
        {
            ResultText.Text = await GetHttpContentWithToken(_graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);
            DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Perform an HTTP GET request to a URL using an HTTP Authorization header
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The URL</param>
    /// <param name="token">The token</param>
    /// <returns>String containing the results of the GET operation</returns>
    public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
    {
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display basic information contained in the token
    /// </summary>
    private void DisplayBasicTokenInfo(AuthenticationResult authResult)
    {
        TokenInfoText.Text = "";
        if (authResult != null)
        {
            TokenInfoText.Text += $"{authResult.Account.Username}";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this API return 1 username in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#)?

Comment: @PamelaPeng no this api request returns all the users (about 700) everythings goes well and i can see all the names in ResultText but not in TokenInfoText. I need TokenInfoText to contain a list of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `TokenInfoText.Text += $"{authResult.Account.Username}";` to set TokenInfoText in your case.

`authResult.Account.Username` just returned the signed-in user which used to get access token, but not the users the API returned.

If you just want to get all displayNames, you could decode the `ResultText.Text` and get the values. [Convert JSON String to JSON Object c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870624/convert-json-string-to-json-object-c-sharp/22870885#22870885).

Also you can use [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) to get the users.

```
private async Task<List<User>> GetUsersFromGraph()
{
    // Create Graph Service Client, refer to https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth
    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) 
            .Build();

    AuthorizationCodeProvider authenticationProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);

    GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

    // Create a bucket to hold the users
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    // Get the first page
    IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage usersPage = await graphServiceClient
        .Users
        .Request()
        .Select(u => new {
            u.DisplayName
        })
        .GetAsync();

    // Add the first page of results to the user list
    users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);

    // Fetch each page and add those results to the list
    while (usersPage.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        usersPage = await usersPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        users.AddRange(usersPage.CurrentPage);
    }

    return users;
}
```

Comment: I am very new to working with azure and graph api, could you please elaborate more on how I could implement this into my code?

Comment: You will get json like `{
  "value": [
    {
      "displayName": "John Smith"
    }
  ]
}`  from GetHttpContentWithToken. I'm not sure what comboboxItem means, if u want the values of displayname, you could convert json to jsonobject and get the list of displaynames

Comment: there are a few things i can't figure out in the code. 1. what do i need to put in ReadParametersFromXML();? 2. what is graphServiceClient? 3. what do i need to put in CreatGraphServiceClient():? 4. is graphClient supposed to be using Neo4jClient? if so it has no definition for Users. Also i suppose that _graphAPIConnectionDetail is the connection url?

Comment: ReadParametersFromXML() is used to get the content of $select, you could ignore it. CreateGraphServiceClient() is used to create graphClient, I will add the method in my answer.

Comment: thank you this helped a lot, however i am running into a problem with AuthorizationCodeProvider the error says i am missing a using directive or assembly reference. How could i solve this issue?

Comment: Have you used [`Microsoft.Graph.Auth`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth#installation-via-nuget) package?

Comment: No i am not using microsoft graph auth i am using microsoft identity client.
Update: i have donwloaded it and it seems to work now, Thank you very much