# How to convert json format string to json in c#

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

Am getting json formatted string which is stored in database, now i want to convert it into json format. How can i convert it Please help.

```
 var labelnames = @"{'LabelName':'LabelName1','IsHeader':true},{'LabelName':'LabelName2','IsHeader':false},{'LabelName':'LabelName3','IsHeader':true},{'LabelName':'LabelName4','IsHeader':false}";
```

I want to convert above code to proper json format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON String to JSON Object c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870624/convert-json-string-to-json-object-c-sharp)

Comment: `labelnames = "[" + labelnames.Replace("'", "\"") + "]"` looks like it should do the trick

Comment: Huh? You have "a json formatted string" but you want to "convert it into json format"?

Comment: That is not a JSON formatted string that you're getting from the database!

Comment: Now is probably also a good time to correct whatever is the *source* of this data so that it gets saved to the DB in JSON format to begin with, which would make this problem moot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is an invalid JSON format, moreover it does not have surrounding array brackets `[]`.** Ideally you should fix this at source.

You could do a simple replace

```cs
MyLabels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Label>>(labelnames = "[" + labelnames.Replace("'", "\"") + "]")
```

However this may throw an error if any of the values also contain a `'`.

**Therefore, you could create a custom `JsonTextReader`**

```cs
        using (var sw = new StringReader("[" + labelnames + "]"))
        using (var reader = new MyJsonTextReader(sw))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            MyLabels = ser.Deserialize<List<Label>>(reader);
        }
```

```cs
    class MyJsonTextReader : JsonTextReader
    {
        public override char QuoteChar { get; protected set; } = '\'';
        
        public MyJsonTextReader(TextReader r) : base(r){}
    }
    class Label
    {
        public string LabelName;
        public bool IsHeader;
    }
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l9xSsB)