# In C# i have a issue with List from returned string

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am receiving from the database a single string with this content

> One;Two;Three

and I want to store those values in the `reportTypeCodes` property in the following class.

```
public class ReportTypeCode
{
    public string codeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime creationDateTime { get; set; }
    public List<ReportTypeCode> reportTypeCodes { get; set; }
}
```

This is my current attempt:

```
Var Obj = new Root(){
           name="Test",
           creationDateTime=Convert.ToDateTime("2021-11-08),
           reportTypeCodes=?? // Don't know how to assign it.
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Should that not be new Root() with a capital R?

Comment: Did you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870624/convert-json-string-to-json-object-c-sharp/22870885

Comment: Just use `.Split(';')` on the String object and then process the resulting array. This seems more like a question for Google than for StackOverflow.

Comment: **Unrelated**: If you have control over the database, storing N report type codes in a single column smells bad, looks like your database could be normalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you want to take your string and split it on every `';'` character. To do this, use `Value.Split(';')`.
Then you want to take each section and turn it into a `ReportTypeCode`. To do this, you can use the LINQ method `Select` like so: `.Select(s => new ReportTypeCode { codeValue = s })`.
Finally, you want to get a list, so you need to call `.ToList()` (it is another LINQ method).
All put together:

```
Value.Split(';').Select(s => new ReportTypeCode { codeValue = s }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `System.Linq` you can do it quite easy, see below^^

```
using System.Linq;
```

```
new Root()
{
     name="Test",
     creationDateTime=Convert.ToDateTime("2021-11-08"),
     reportTypeCodes= "One;Two;Three"
           .Split(';')
           .Select(x => new ReportTypeCode(){codeValue = x})
           .ToList()
}
```

Comment: explicit cast missing Error.

Comment: Why the heck would you want to create such a unnecessary lambda when you can populate the list with a couple of constructors?

Comment: It might also be better, when dealing with a beginning programmer, to make them aware of the the existence of the "for" loop, rather than going straight to Linq.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in the following way:

```cs
var Obj = new Root()
{
    name = "Test",
    creationDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2021-11-08"),    
   reportTypeCodes = new List<ReportTypeCode>(){
        new ReportTypeCode(){ codeValue = "one"},
        new ReportTypeCode(){ codeValue = "two" }
   }
};
```

Comment: Hi Mario... for known length of strings we can write above but String Value we are not sure whether it may 3 or more. it comes from DB. so code wise we need to iterate. Can you pls help me for my case.

Comment: @KalyanReddy Then you need to write code to iterate these database results and make them into a list. That's unrelated to the code you showed though. `List` has a `.Add()` function exactly for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on what you want to do...

```
        var rootTest = new Root();

        rootTest.reportTypeCodes = new List<ReportTypeCode>()
        {
            new ReportTypeCode()
            {
                codeValue = "hello world"
            },
            new ReportTypeCode()
            {
                codeValue = "hello world 2"
            },
        };

        foreach(var code in rootTest.reportTypeCodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(code.codeValue);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
Var Obj = new root(){
           name="Test",
           creationDateTime=Convert.ToDateTime("2021-11-08),
           reportTypeCodes= new List<ReportTypeCode>{
               new ReportTypeCode { codeValue = "A"; },
               new ReportTypeCode { codeValue = "B"; }
           }
    }
```